# Attaching labels to messages in Gmail via IMAP using code

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, gmail, imap

concerning Gmail labels - what are they technically speaking. I mean through imap connection I can access a gmail mailbox and go through the emails however let say I wish to create a label and attach it to the emails as I loop through them using code - how can I do that in code? I'm using php - and Zend Framework.

EDIT ===

Thanks for the replies so its now clear that labels are treated like folders in this respect however I've tried the Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap class functions with interesting results. If I try the Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap:moveMessage function - it removes the message from wherever it is and literally attaches a label to it meaning if I wish to attach a label foo to my message it removes it form the inbox and attaches the label foo. However if I use Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap::copyMessage that does the trick.

However I'm wondering here that doesn't this literally make a duplicate copy of the message and you end up with more than one duplicate message right here?

Also what if I need to select all the messages that are attached with a certain label or in this case within a certain folder?

Comment: Re: does copyMessage duplicate the message? Not in GMail. GMail re-defines "folders" to mean labels. So the messages are not duplicated. Rather labels are applied or removed. To select all messages with a particular label, use the imap operation select(label) to select the "folder" followed by imap search to retrieve the message ids of the messages in the "folder"--the messages with the desired label

Comment: Great that works perfectly - but if I want to select all emails within the INBOX that are NOT tagged with a certain label.. how would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Re: concerning Gmail labels - what are they technically speaking.

Since IMAP doesn't have the concept of "labels", there is a mapping, more or less, between GMail "labels" and IMAP "folders" [Here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77657) is the best doc I found on it. But what really helped me in creating my programmatic IMAP interaction with GMail was experimentation.

For example, the preset labels have IMAP folder names of

```
Human name -- IMAP Folder name
Drafts -- [Gmail]/Drafts
Sent Mail -- [Gmail]/Sent Mail
Spam -- [Gmail]/Spam
Starred -- [Gmail]/Starred
Trash -- [Gmail]/Trash
```

Added--

**Re: create a label and attach it to the emails as I loop through them using code - how can I do that in code?**

To create a label, use the Imap 'create folder' operation.

Use the Imap copy operation to add a label to a message.

To remove the message from the GMail Inbox, I am 90% sure that you add the IMAP Flag 'Deleted'. -- But please experiment with this first. It is not clear to me which label(s) are removed when you set the deleted flag. In my tests, the message only had 1 label (Inbox) when I applied the deleted flag.

Here is the code I use for moving a GMail message from Inbox to the Trash folder:

```
# Ruby code...
imap.store(message_id, "+FLAGS", [:Deleted]) # rm inbox label
imap.copy(message_id, "[Gmail]/Trash")       # add trash label
```

Comment: Hmmm so basically the labels map to IMAP folders - cool - so if I were to 'apply' a label to a message in Gmail using my own php code.. how would I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the php imap library. It should expose the various Imap procedures of 'create folder', 'copy to folder', etc.

Answer (score 3):

For PHP have you tried `imap_mail_move`?

http://ro.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php

Comment: `imap_mail_move` will apply the label, and remove the message from inbox (archive message). Use `imap_mail_copy` if you want to apply the label, but still keep the message in inbox.

Comment: Found that out the hard way thanks for the input - check out my update!

Answer (score 2):

Gmail supports storing of labels on a per message basis:

```
a011 STORE 1 +X-GM-LABELS (foo)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante" foo))
a011 OK STORE (Success)
```

From their API Tools site: http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/#x-gm-labels

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party here, but people might find this information from https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions useful:

> Gmail treats labels as folders for the purposes of IMAP. As such, labels can be modified using the standard IMAP commands, `CREATE`, `RENAME`, and `DELETE`, that act on folders. System labels, which are labels created by Gmail, are reserved and prefixed by "[Gmail]" or "[GoogleMail]" in the list of labels. Use the `XLIST` command to get the entire list of labels for a mailbox.
>
> The labels for a given message may be retrieved by using the `X-GM-LABELS` attribute with the `FETCH` command. The attribute is returned as a list of `ASTRING`s, encoded in UTF-7 as appropriate. An `ASTRING` is an [atom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4.1) or a [string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4.3) as defined by the RFC.
>
> The following is an example transcript of a call to retrieve the `X-GM-LABELS` of several messages with the `FETCH` command:

```
a010 FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-LABELS)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante"))
* 2 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (foo))
* 3 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ())
* 4 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Drafts))
a010 OK FETCH (Success)
```

> Labels may be added to a message using the `STORE` command in conjunction with the `X-GM-LABELS` attribute. The following is an example transcript demonstrating the addition of a label to a message:

```
a011 STORE 1 +X-GM-LABELS (foo)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante" foo))
a011 OK STORE (Success)
```

> The `X-GM-LABELS` attribute may also be used in the `SEARCH` or `UID SEARCH` commands to find the sequence numbers or `UID`s of all messages in the folder with a given label. The following is an example transcript of a call to retrieve the sequence numbers of several messages using the `SEARCH` command:

```
a012 SEARCH X-GM-LABELS foo
* SEARCH 1 2
a012 OK SEARCH (Success)
```